# Close xceed Child Window on escape button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, childwindow

I'm using xceed wpf Toolkit.
In that I'm using ChildWindow. I need to close the opened Child window on escape key press. Here is the code

```
<xctk:ChildWindow x:Name="ChildVendorsEdit" IsModal="True" WindowStartupLocation="Center" Caption="Edit" >
//My Content Here
</xctk:ChildWindow>
```

Can you help me ??

Answer (score 1):

Use the "IsCancel" Property on your Button.

```
<Button Content="Discard" Click="ButtonDiscard_OnClick" IsCancel="True"></Button>
```

Same for IsDefault (Enter Key)

Answer (score 0):

If you use version 2.0.0 or higher you should put `ChildWindow` in `WindowContainer` and use `PreviewKeyDown` event.

*XAML:*

```
<xctk:WindowContainer>
    <xctk:ChildWindow x:Name="ChildVendorsEdit" IsModal="True" WindowStartupLocation="Center" Caption="Edit"                          
                  PreviewKeyDown="ChildVendorsEdit_PreviewKeyDown" >                
    </xctk:ChildWindow>
</xctk:WindowContainer>
```

*Code-behind:*

```
private void ChildVendorsEdit_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        (sender as Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ChildWindow).WindowState = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.WindowState.Closed;
    }
}
```

If you use version below 2.0.0 you should use `PreviewKeyDown` event:

*XAML:*

```
<xctk:ChildWindow x:Name="ChildVendorsEdit" IsModal="True" WindowStartupLocation="Center" Caption="Edit"                          
                  PreviewKeyDown="ChildVendorsEdit_PreviewKeyDown" >            
</xctk:ChildWindow>
```

*Code-behind:*

```
private void ChildVendorsEdit_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        (sender as Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ChildWindow).WindowState = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.WindowState.Closed;
    }
}
```

To close `ChildWindow` in `PreviewKeyDown` event handler you have two options:

- you can set `WindowState` to `Closed`,
- or you can invoke `Close` method.